# How to handle HiddenField with Flask?

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm having trouble understanding how to use hidden forms in this situation, or even if I should be using this technique at all.
My main page, `all_products.html`,  will have a list of products, each with a link in the form of a button to see more details for that product:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="editer">
    {{ form1.prodid(value="car") }}
    {{ form1.prodyear(value="2012") }}
    <a href="{{ url_for('edit_product', product='car') }}">
        <input type="button" value="Edit" />
    </a><br>
</form>
<form action="" method="post" name="editer">
    {{ form2.prodid(value="truck") }}
    {{ form2.prodyear(value="1999") }}
    <a href="{{ url_for('edit_product', product='truck') }}">
        <input type="button" value="Edit" />
    </a><br>
</form>
```

The template is created with

```
@app.route('/all_products', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def all_products():
    form1 = AllProductsForm()
    form2 = AllProductsForm()
    return render_template('all_products.html', form1=form1, form2=form2)
```

The AllProductsForm is:

```
class AllProductsForm(Form):
    prodid = HiddenField('myfield')
    prodyear = HiddenField('myfield')
```

The edit_product.html is templated using:

```
@app.route('/productedit/<product>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_product(product):
    form =  AllProductsForm()
    print form.prodid.data
    return render_template('edit_product.html')
```

This doesn't seem to be doing what I want. I would like edit_product() to have access to the form containing the data from the button click, but it is empty.

Is there some other way I should be doing this? In the real version, I won't just have 2 products, but many that are looped through.

Comment: You are wrapping the buttons with a link.. you are not submiting the form, i think you don't want a form there.. you can have prodid, and prodyear on the url route and change the url_for

Comment: ie. @app.route('/productedit/<product>/<year>', methods=['GET', 'POST']) and url_for('edit_product', product="truck", year="1999")

Comment: But in my real life version a product will have many more attributes. I don't want to have to end up with something like `@app.route('/productedit/<product>/<year>/<price>/<model>/<color>/<size>/<etc...>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])'

Comment: So, you just need an id, and fetch from the database or where you store the products, i guess..

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I was wondering if I should avoid doing that because on my "all_products" page I will have already fetched all the data, why fetch again on the "edit_product" page if I already have the data?

Comment: If you edit in place, that makes sense, but here you are sending the data to the server and then sending to the browser again, i don't think that would be any faster, if not slower, than querying the database again..